# How to stop Blender from resetting tool with Undo?

Tags: interface

Most of the time when I undo (Ctrl+Z) Blender not only undoes an operation but also resets any tool I am using a step back or several steps back, for example, I have a locked vertex group, unlock it, do something like weight paint but make a mistake so I press Ctrl+Z and it not only undoes the painting but also locks the group and sometimes even goes to the last selection and tool I used which messes up the workflow and sometimes even deletes certain things like custom colors on a palette, resets brush settings, etc.

Is it a feature? how can I disable that so only the very last step is undone?

Comment: it's a problem in the last versions, I hope it will be corrected, you can give a thumb up to this request: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Jtfbbc/

Comment: Hello :). I voted to close this question as Bug related, because it's a High Priority bug [already reported here](https://developer.blender.org/T71759). Hope it get's fixed soon.

Comment: OK, glad to know I am not the only one with the problem.